# How to make an exe file to connect SQL Server and export excel file by using pyinstaller?

Tags: python, sql, excel, pyinstaller

Due to there isn't python in some partner's computer , I plan to create an exe file by pyinstaller, then they could use the exe file.
The exe file will connect SQL server, then export an excel file.
The code is following.

```
import pyodbc 
import pandas as pd
from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl.utils.dataframe import dataframe_to_rows
filename = input('Please input excel filename: ')
start_date = input('Please input start date: ')
end_date = input('Please input end date: ')
stage = input('Please input stage: ')


Driver = 'Driver'
server = 'server ' 
username = 'username ' 
password = 'password '
Filter = "SELECT * FROM openquery (A, 'SELECT * FROM B WHERE C > ''" + start_date +"'' ')"

conn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={'+Driver+'};SERVER='+server+';UID='+username+';PWD='+ password)
cursor = conn.cursor() 

sql = Filter
SQL_query = read_sql_query(sql,conn)
Df = DataFrame(SQL_query)
cursor.close
print('Close.')

wb = Workbook()
ws = wb.active
for r in dataframe_to_rows(Df, index=True, header=True):
    ws.append(r)
wb.save(filename + ".xlsx")
print('Done.')
```

I can compile the code by jupyter, the result can export the data which I query by SQL to excel file.
But, something wrong happened when I used anaconda prompt and typed

```
pyinstaller -F filename.py
```

it can't work to create an exe file.

The error message is following,

> Unable to find "D:\python\lib\site-packages\win32\pywintypes37.dll
> Could not open file mapping object (2)." when adding binary and data files.

I checked that the pywintypes37.dll file is at D:\python\lib\site-packages\win32\ .
I used other code to create an exe file by pyinstaller, and it worked.
It made me confused, what is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

At runtime pyinstaller can not find the DLL it seems. You can specify it manually in your rebuild. such as

```
pyinstaller -F --add-binary="D:\python\lib\site-packages\win32\pywintypes37.dll" filename.py
```

If you need to add more DLL's or if you want pyinstaller to add a path to analysis you can use the pyinstaller spec file with the pathex variables.